# Guava BloomFilter how to expire once a day

Tags: guava, bloom-filter

I am using guava bloom filter to remove duplicate message in the service for receiving log.
Is there a way for bloom filter to expire like guava cache does?

Comment: The answers below are correct, but did you perhaps want to expire the *entire* cache every day, rather than individual entries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, a `BloomFilter` does not have any remove functionality. This is also impossible, since a `BloomFilter` keeps track of what *may* possibly be in a set of objects.

Removing an entry from a `BloomFilter` for one entry would result into false negatives for other entries. A `BloomFilter` must be 100% accurate about what is *not* in the set.

Answer (score 2):

You can't even remove from Guava's `BloomFilter`, let alone automatically expire entries.

Answer (score 2):

If you need remove functionality consider using a **Counting Bloom Filter**.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Tavian Barnes, one solution here might be to create a class that wraps a `BloomFilter` and (once a day, or however often you want) atomically replaces that `BloomFilter` with a new one and repopulates it.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using Sliding Bloom Filters

Check this, This can solve your problem

https://programming.guide/sliding-bloom-filter.html